# I can't see my SSD as bootable option in BIOS

Tags: ssd

I cloned my hard drive to an SSD. The next step would be to make the SSD bootable.

How do I verify if SSD is bootable or not? It's active. It's system. How do I make it bootable?

Why BIOS do not recognize the SSD as a bootable option? What should I do so it is?

The SSD is currently drive E under the windows operating system I am in.  I just want to boot from that SSD.

Acronis OS selector also can't detect an operating system in the SSD.

```
Not hyper-threaded
Board: ECS H61H2-M12 1.0
Bus Clock: 400 megahertz
BIOS: American Megatrends Inc. 4.6.4 08/05/2011
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the BIOS lists "Hard drive" as a boot option, there may be another BIOS settings that lets you order the hard drives.  Whichever one is set to to the top will be the "Hard drive" used in the boot order selection.

This is based on the assumption that you have desktop board that performs this way, but it's hard to say for sure based on the info you've provided (so far).  To get a more accurate answer, perhaps edit your question to add your motherboard make/model, current BIOS version, as well as describe what boot options *are* available.

Comment: How do I know my current bios version?

Comment: Depends on the specific BIOS, but in general: Look in the BIOS. :)

Comment: You are correct. I can select hard disk and after that I need to be able to select the sequences of hard disk.

Answer (score 1):

Did you open your BIOS configuration and try changing the boot priority? Try moving your SSD to the top of the boot priority list, save the configuration, and reboot.

If your SSD is not visible in the boot list, then this problem is not related to Windows. I would Google your specific SSD model and see if there are any known issues.

I don't know whether a BIOS update ever has something to do with SSD incompatibility, but it's such an easy thing to do so I probably would do it just to clear that from the list.

Comment: The SSD shows up at other places in BIOS, but not the one wherre I want to select boot.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could load up a system rescue CD like Hiren's boot disc and get into partition magic to look at the partition properties of the disc.