# Old notebook can't boot from SSD / can't install Windows

Tags: hard-drive, boot, laptop, ssd

a friend got himself a SanDisk SSD Plus for his nearly seven year old notebook. Unfortunately, he can't install Windows on it, because, as the Windows Setup told us, the Notebook is unable to boot from the SSD.

And that's pretty much it. His Samsung R519 back from 2010 can't boot from a SanDisk SSD Plus built in 2016 and I just have no clue, why. I am unable to select the SSD as boot device in BIOS. The SanDisk SSD works fine in my (2011) Dell XPS 15 and his notebook has no problems booting from my Samsung 840 SSD.

For all I ever thought, all our hard drives and controllers use and support AHCI since long before 2010 and also up to the present day. And yeah, the SSD is recognized, it's just not bootable.
What piece am I missing? Why won't this combination work?

Maybe this is easy, I just don't know what to search for exactly.

Oh, for the record: All tested disks were checked to use DOS partitioning, no GPT around.

Comment: Try to disable the Secure Boot option , if available . Make sure the SSD is in SATA port 0.

Answer (score 0):

Try answer in "[I can't see my SSD as bootable option in BIOS](https://superuser.com/questions/559823/i-cant-see-my-ssd-as-bootable-option-in-bios)"

> "...there may be another BIOS settings that lets you order the hard drives."

or maybe **theadler** on http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-2120026/ssd-problems-bios-boot-option.html described it a bit better.

> In your bios, under the boot menu, is there a a tab or link for Hard Drive BBS Priorities? If there is, in it change the first drive to your SSD, if it is in the drop down list. Then go back to the boot menu and the drive should show up under boot priorities. I don't know if your bios has this option, but mine does and I had a similar problem right after installing windows.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no such option. Besides that, there was only one Hard Drive attached to the system at any given time, so this should be no issue. Oh, and the Boot order screen shows no "Hard Drive" option, but already specific device names.